# 7zip; Running from command line

Tags: python, cmd, compression, zip, 7zip

I have a pretty weird error. I'm creating a .bat file in Python, and then run it via os.system(). This .bat file contains 2 7zip commands, but when I run the Python program I get the error "**7z is not recognized as an internal or external command......**".

HOWEVER. When i'm going to the cmd, and navigate where the created .bat file is, and call it from the cmd, it works O_O.

How come that it can't find 7z when I run a batch file via os.system? While calling the batch file via cmd works. (I thought this is practically the same?)

```
# Windows 7
# Works when calling Temp.bat directly via cmd, but not via os.system() in Python
File = open(Temp.bat, 'w')
File.write('7z a '+[path to new .7z]+' '+[path to file]+' -r')
File.close()
os.system(Temp.bat)
```

Comment: It is nuts to run a batch file with `os.system`. Use `subprocess` module instead.

Comment: I use the batch file for multiple purposes, including the zipping part. Also when trying this with winzip I have the same problem.

Comment: Please show your code: in particular, the line you use for executing the 7z command.

Comment: Try using the full path to 7z command

Comment: I have tried, no success. However when running the Python file within the cmd, it works again. But thats not how I want it......

Comment: It work for me: File.write('cd  C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\ \n 7z.exe a  full_path\\new.7z full_path\\file.txt -r'). Maybe it will be useful.